# Own exception in C++ can not be thrown

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to get a custom exception in C++ working (Linux, g++). `Dictionary.hpp`:

```
#ifndef HEADER_DICTIONARY_H
#define HEADER_DICTIONARY_H

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

[...]

class EDictionaryNoLabel : public runtime_error
{
public:
          explicit EDictionaryNoLabel(const string& __arg);
          virtual ~EDictionaryNoLabel() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
};

#endif
```

And in `Dictionary.cpp` I throw the exception (here is where the compilation fails):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "Dictionary.hpp"

using namespace std;

//  map<string, string> dictMap;
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
}

void Dictionary::update(string label, string value) {
        dictMap[label]=value;
}

string Dictionary::read(string label){
        if (0==dictMap.count(label)) {
                throw( EDictionaryNoLabel("label not found") );
        }
        return dictMap[label];
}

void Dictionary::refresh() {
        dictMap.clear();
}
```

But I can not compile it:

```
utils/Dictionary.o: In function `Dictionary::read(std::string)':
Dictionary.cpp:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `EDictionaryNoLabel::EDictionaryNoLabel(std::string const&)'
Dictionary.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `EDictionaryNoLabel::~EDictionaryNoLabel()'
Dictionary.cpp:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `typeinfo for EDictionaryNoLabel'
/tmp/ccXT7dWk.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x68): undefined reference to `typeinfo for EDictionaryNoLabel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test] Error 1
```

I write my exception exactly as the standard `overflow_error` (also inheriting from `runtime_error`).

Comment: And where's your definition for the exceptions constructor destructor?

Comment: thank you πάντα ῥεῖ  for your comment. Aren't the constructor and destructor inherited from ```runtime_error```? I don't need any special behaviour, I just need a new exception.

Comment: No, constructors/destructors can't be inherited without implementation, they must be specified uniquely for each class. You can specify the base class constructor in the member initializer list of your implementation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy and effective way to derive your own exceptions is:

```
struct EDictionaryNoLabel : std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

That's it.

This gives you all the standard constructors and type-safety. Plus you can add further methods if you need them.

anticipating:

> What does `using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;` do?

copies the names of the base class's constructors into this class's namespace. It gives you all the base class's constructors with no extra code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After so many years of programming using many languages, it is quite frustrating to spend so much time to get an exception working. You solution is nice because it is very compact. The connection of struct with a class is surprising me.

Comment: @LiPo in c++ a struct and a class are the same thing except that a struct is public by default and inherits publicly by default. Since most classes need public constructors and most derived classes need to publish their base class interfaces, I'm amazed that anyone uses the keyword 'class' at all. It just seems to me like a waste of typing effort.